# A is a nxn matrix with zero as an eigenvalue. Show that $A$ is not invertible.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with zero as an eigenvalue. Show that $A$ is not invertible.

Hint: Assume that $A$ is invertible and compute $A^-1*Av$ where v is an eigenvector of A corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.

Can you also explain what zero as an eigenvalue is telling me/ adding to te quesiton.

Please help!

Comment: Av=0 since the matrix has zero as an eigenvalue, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A(u)=0, u\neq 0$ and $A$ invertible, $u=A^{-1}A(u)=A^{-1}(0)=0$ contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

Since $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\det A$ is the product of eigenvalues of $A$, so $\det A$  must be zero. Thus $A$ is not invertible.